# __NSCFString playbackFinished unrecognized selector from MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using `MPMoviePlayerController` inside a class Ive built called `MYVideo`. Here is the code:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "MYVideo.h"

@interface MYVideo()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView * viewRef;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary * contentData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController * videoController;
@end

@implementation MYVideo
@synthesize contentData,videoController,viewRef;

- (MYVideo*) initIntoView: (UIView*) view withContent:(NSDictionary*)contentDict{
    self=[super init];
    viewRef=view;
    contentData = contentDict;
    NSString *rawUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://....com/app/%@.mp4", [contentDict objectForKey:@"cnid"]];
    NSURL *videoUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:rawUrl];
    videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
    videoController.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    videoController.view.frame = viewRef.bounds;
    [videoController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    videoController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playbackFinished:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:videoController];
    [viewRef addSubview:videoController.view];
    return self;
}

- (void) playbackFinished: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"playback finished");
    if(videoController){
        [videoController play];
    }
}

- (void) play: (int) offset {
    videoController.initialPlaybackTime=offset;
    [videoController play];
}

- (void) stop {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"playbackFinished"
                                                  object:nil];
    if(videoController){
        [videoController stop];
    }
}

- (void) destroy {
    if(videoController){
        [videoController stop];
        [videoController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
@end
```

My problem is that occasionally I get the following error:

```
playback finished
-[__NSCFString playbackFinished:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1664e6a0
```

Which I'm guessing is caused by the `MPMoviePlayerController` firing off the "playbackFinished" notification when this video class has already been released. Am I right in thinking this?

Thing is, this `MYVideo` class should still be there while the video is playing, this error only occurs when the video is playing and in the console log my NSLogging of "playback finished" immeditately preceeds the crash. Also I never shut down the class without first removing the "playbackFinished" observer.

Can anybody suggest to me why I would be getting this crash?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it looks like you are not removing the observer, as this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"playbackFinished"
                                              object:nil];
```

should be:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"playbackFinished:"
                                              object:nil];         //  ^
```

or better still (as you don't really care what's being called):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:nil
                                              object:videoController];
```

Also given you use tests like `if (videoController) { ... }` in so many places, you need to ensure it goes `nil` ASAP:

```
- (void)destroy {
    if(videoController){
        [videoController stop];
        [videoController.view removeFromSuperview];
        videoController = nil;   // Add
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks! ive been staring at this code for hours, and i missed a damn typo! gah... cheers for the advice too.